# Mongoose find with or condition not working as expected

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I want to find whether the string exist either in the `shop_name` or `name` inside the `food` in the schema.

Here is the query

```
dbModel.stores.find({ "food.name": { '$regex': re } }).or([{ 'shop_name': { '$regex': re } }]).exec(function(err, docs) {
        if (!err) {
            res.status(200).json({
                "success": "1",
                "message": docs
            });
        } else {
            res.status(200).json({
                "success": "0",
                "message": "No result found"
            });
        }
    });
```

Here's my schema

```
var storeSchema = {
    "area": String,
    "food": [{
        'name': String,
        'description': String
    }],
    "shop_name": String
};
```

I want to show the record which matches with the string either in the `shop_name` or `food.name`

The above gives me the record only if the string contains in both the element. How can i get check with `or` i.e., If shop_name or food.name was matched then it should display it

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to place your conditions within the [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) array.

Because `food` is an array of objects, you may need to use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) in your first condition.

I've never done this before, but it would look like:

```
dbModel.stores.find({ 
    $or: [
        { 
           food: { 
               $elemMatch: { name: { $regex: re }}
           }
        }, 
        { 
           shop_name: { $regex: re }
        }
    ] 
}).exec(...)
```

[Another reference](https://mfcoding.wordpress.com/2014/03/28/mongodb-query-an-array-of-documents/)